# Is it possible to gradually increase/decrease values using arrow keys?

Tags: node-editor, interface, workflow, lighting

When I'm changing the values in Blender (for instance in the nodes) I find it kind of inconvenient to type in the new values or using the slider. Especially, if it's about subtle adjustments. The slider is often lagging if the preview is heavy. In Adobe Programs you can change the values gradually by using the arrow keys. But it doesn't seem to work for Blender. Is there another way to do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can hold the mouse over the slider, hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and scroll the mouse wheel. This will change the value incrementally.